# How to find duplicate entries in database using Propel ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I want to look for duplicate entries in my table and show all of them. How can I find all duplicated values in one column using Propel ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields) suggests using counts... you could replicate that query in Propel (I think) with this:

```
$results = TableNameQuery::create()
  ->select(array("id", "field", "COUNT(*)"))
  ->groupBy("field")
  ->having("COUNT(*) > ?", 1)
  ->find();
```

Of course, this gets a little hairy, so you might just want to use straight SQL if Propel fails you.

(For reference, here's the SQL:)

```
SELECT field, COUNT(*)
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY field
  HAVING count(*) > 1
```