# MySQL look for duplicates on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL database with the following fields:

```
id, email, first_name, last_name
```

I want to run an SQL query that will display rows where id and email exists more than once.

Basically, the id and email field should only have one row and I would like to run a query to see if there are any possible duplicates

Comment: Does your database structure define id as a primary key? If it does, there should be no way you have duplicates.

Comment: no, i have another field that is a primary key called member_id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to return the id and email that are duplicated, you can just use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, email
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

if you also want to return the full rows, then you have to join the previous query back:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, email
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY id, email
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  ) s
  ON yourtable.id = s.id AND yourtable.email=s.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this:

```
select field1,field2,field3, count(*)
from table_name
group by field1,field2,field3
having count(*) > 1
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for all ids that meet a specific count by grouping them and using a having clause like this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS totalCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Anything this query returns has a duplicate. To check for duplicate emails, you can just change the column you're selecting.