# Find rows with duplicate entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to find rows with duplicate order numbers in a table in SQL Server.

For example SELECT * shows:

```
No
-----
5001
5002
5003
5003
5003
5004
5005
5006
5006
```

I want to get

```
No
------
5003
5003
5003
5006
5006
```

Is it possible to write a query to do that?

Comment: You haven't found anything in your research about duplicates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why did your answer disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was answered thousand times on SO, use `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`:

```
SELECT No
FROM dbo.tablename
Group By No
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.No
  FROM [dbo].[Shows] S
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT [No]
      FROM [dbo].[Shows]
      GROUP BY [No]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) J
    ON S.No = J.No
```

Comment: But I can't imagine why do you want this subset of data:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT() OVER()` to get count of rows per `No` and, in an outer query, filter out all non-duplicate rows:

```
SELECT [No]
FROM (
   SELECT [No], COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [No]) AS cnt
   FROM mytable ) t
WHERE cnt > 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/888e9/1)