# SQL duplicate persons multiple tables?

Tags: sql, list, duplicates

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will give me a list of duplicate persons in a database. I can not create a new table with this query.

I'm trying to find where persons have matching first name, last name and dates of birth.

The names are held in a table `persons` and dates of birth are stored in `personsInfo` linked with a matching id.

Comment: You better include table schema and sample data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with:

```
select p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName, I.DoB, count(*)
from persons as p
join personsInfo as I
on p.ID = i.PersonsID
group by p.firstname, p.lastName, I.DoB
having count(*) > 1
```

Found the answer by searching "select duplicates sql" and looking at [this question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)