# Check for dupes in db with TWO rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I´d like to check for dupes in MySQL comparing two columns:

Linked duplicate doesn't match as it's about finding the duplicate values on specific columns. This question is about finding the rows which have said duplicate values.

Example:

```
id    Column1    Column2
-------------------------
       3          1     <-This row is a dupe
       3          2
       3          3
       3          1     <-This row is a dupe
```

I'd like to have a list like this:

```
id    Column1    Column2
-------------------------
        3        1
        3        1
```

How should this query look like?

My thinking:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Column1 && Column2 is a dupe ;)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

Comment: Linked duplicate doesn't match as it's about *finding the duplicate values* on specific columns. This question is about *finding the rows* which have said duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to find the duplicates:

```
SELECT column1, column2
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY column1, column2
 HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

And to show the actual duplicate rows you can `JOIN` against results of the above query:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable yt1
 JOIN (SELECT column1, column2
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY column1, column2
 HAVING count(*) > 1) yt2 ON (yt2.column1=yt1.column1 AND yt2.column2=yt1.column2);
```

Comment: What is yt1 and yt2? "Yourtable 1" etc?

Comment: @Mjukis : yes its yourtable 1 and yourtable2

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I did not change "yt1" or "yt2". What do you do, when you use it after "yourtable"? Can i read up on this?

Comment: No these are simply alias to your table names . You can use them as it is.

Comment: As @naggarwal11 correctly pointed out, `yt1` and `yt2` are aliases (abbreviations). `yt1` is just a alias for `yourtable` while `yt2` is alias for result set of the subquery.

Comment: Well, when i look at the result now i may have bin a little rushy. Some result i do not understand why they came up. I used: "FROM mytable yt1..." Should i remove "yt1.column2" to "mytable.column2". But where does yt2 come from? i have only 1 table.. with two columns.. i want to check..

Comment: You mean they are "placeholders"? When i write: "mytable yt1" i put "mytable" into "yt1"?

Comment: If you change `yourtable` into `mytable` you don't need to change `yt1` or `yt2`. It is correct that you have only one table, but you may consider `yt2` as a temporary table that exists only during this query.

Comment: Yes, you might call them placeholders. I prefer to call them aliases as that's also used in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

Comment: @vhu I tried to add "ORDER BY" whitout no succes. I get a query error. Where can i add this prop?

Comment: reminder that you have a link to the documentation right above

Answer (score 0):

```
select * , count(column1)
from table
group by column1, column2
having (count(column1) >1)
```

that is one solution. you will get all columns which exist more than one time, through the having. and the group by collects all together. the count could also go on both or column 2, that is not so important

Comment: With this code, i only get ONE row from each dupplicate. I need to se each two(or more) rows!

Comment: select * , count(column1)
from table
group by column1, column2
having (count(column1) >1)

Comment: oh sorry my fault
`select * , count(column1, column1)
from table
having (count(column1) >1)`
i think this should help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will provide you all the duplicate entries

```
select column1,column2 from table_name group by column1,column2 having count(column1)>1
```

Comment: @naggarwall11 This code will only give me one of each dupes. Not ALL the dupes entries.