# How to query for all of one item with duplicates of another item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that reports all labels placed in a set of drawings. Each label has a file name and drawing number. I want to filter this table for all entries of a certain file name and duplicates of the drawing number. This will tell me which drawings have multiples of the same label. For example, the picture in the link below shows that I have three of Label 1 in DWG#1 and two of label #1 in DWG#2. This tells me that I need to clean up the duplicates in these two drawings. I need a statement to run in SQL Server to report these entries. Thanks!

[image: Example]

Comment: Providing sample data in the form of an image is discouraged here is SO. Please use properly formatted text for this purpose.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the count(*) function to determine how many duplicates are there in the table.

select count(*), colomn_filename, colomn_drawingnumber 
from table_name 
group by colomn_filename, colomn_drawingnumber 
having count(*)>1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fileName, drawingNo, count(*) FROM TableName 
GROUP BY fileName, drawingNo
```

Result:

Label 1   DWG#1    3

Label 1   DWG#2    2

If you really need the result same as yours then use left join

```
SELECT a.fileName, a.drawingNo FROM TableName a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT fileName, drawingNo FROM TableName 
GROUP BY fileName, drawingNo 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b ON a.fileName = b.fileName AND a.drawingNo = b.drawingNo
```