# SQL to detect adjacent duplicate rows (duplicates indicated by values in subset of columns)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to hunt down a potential bug in my application, and I'd like to see if there are duplicate events recorded for a user, which would be evidenced by duplicate data in two columns, `user` and `value` whereas the other columns could have slightly different meta data. Is there a way to identify such duplicates in a single SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

Comment: Adjacent? Then you can use LAG or LEAD to see the previous or next record. Or use an EXISTS clause to find records where exists another record in the same minute or so with the same user and value.

Answer (score 1):

[Window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) functions can be used here. Especifically `lag` or `lead` deppending if you want the previous or the next occurrence of the dupplicate.

This query uses `lag` but can be safely changed by `lead`:

```
WITH event_with_lag_data AS (
SELECT user, value, value_ts,
  lag(user) over (order by value_ts) as prev_user,
  lag(value) over (order by value_ts) as prev_value 
FROM event_data
)
SELECT user, value, value_ts
FROM event_with_lag_data
WHERE user = prev_user AND value = prev_value
```

`value_ts` is the ordering column. I assume events are ordered by date/time.
If you have more columns to test for equality is just a matter of adding more lines to the `lag` part and to the final `where` part

Answer (score 0):

In case you are just looking to find any duplicates based on two columns since it isn't clear what you mean by "adjacent", here is a solution:

```
    WITH duplicates AS (
      select
        user,
        value,
        COUNT(*) AS COUNT
      FROM event_data
      GROUP BY 
        user, 
        value
    )

    SELECT 
      user,
      value
    FROM duplicates
    WHERE COUNT > 1
```