# How to delete all rows with duplicate values in 2 columns but keep the last inserted row?

Tags: sqlite

Given the following table:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| id | val1   | val2   | timestamp  |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| 1  | 50     | 100    | 1471869500 |
| 2  | 50     | 100    | 1471869800 |
| 3  | 60     | 70     | 1471864400 |
| 4  | 60     | 80     | 1471863300 |
| 5  | 60     | 90     | 1471862200 |
| 6  | 60     | 100    | 1471861100 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

I want to remove any rows that have duplicate values in columns val1 and val2 (so that would be rows 1 and 2) but keep the row that was inserted last (row 2).
In the example table only row 1 would be removed.

Hoe do I create an SQLite statement that does this for me?

I have tried:

[Select statement to find duplicates on certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields)

[Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101697/sqlite3-remove-duplicates-by-multiple-columns

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that SQLite does not support direct joining in its `DELETE` syntax, but you can still use a correlated subquery to get the job done.  Try this query:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE timestamp t <> (SELECT MAX(p.timestamp) FROM yourTable p
                      WHERE p.val1 = t.val1 AND p.val2 = t.val2)
```

Comment: I should have changed the timestamps for the other rows more I see. When the timestamps are different this query does not work properly. It did work great for the example though :)

I will update the example table in the original question.

Please see sqlfiddle.com/#!7/22503/1

Comment: @GijsdeJong You are misinterpreting the SQL Fiddle.  When you apply my query logic to a `SELECT`, you will return the records which you _do_ want to delete.  For most of your data, there is only one record per (`val1`, `val2`) group.  In this case, no records will be selected out.  During a delete, the opposite will happen, and the records selected out will be deleted.

Comment: True, but could you think of a solution where the rows would be deleted by id? The actual data I am working with contains a lot more rows and I can not be sure that deletion by timestamp will never delete more rows than I would like.

Comment: Your requirement necessitates using the timestamp in the query.  If you want to restrict deletion to a range of ids, then just add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for you help :)

Comment: @GijsdeJong Not a problem, any time :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I run the fiddle most of the data set is wiped out and only id=5 remains.
So given:

> I want to remove any rows that have duplicate values in columns val1
> and val2 (so that would be rows 1 and 2) but keep the row that was
> inserted last (row 2). In the example table only row 1 would be
> removed.

This should do the trick and remove row 1 only:

```
SELECT * FROM queue
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT MAX(rowid) 
  FROM queue 
  GROUP BY val1, val2
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6cc1d/1