# SQL - How to return all column fields for one column containing duplicates

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to get to grips with SQL as I'm implementing SQLite into my existing program.

I'm trying to work out how to display the results of a search for duplicate values in one particular column, and where duplicates are found, I want ALL the rows that correspond to the column cell where a duplicate was found, to be displayed.

For example, for data in the database is :

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
Peter    | Smith    | 1234
Claire   | Walter   | 1234
Sandra   | Kay      | 0000
Oliver   | Meeson   | 3456
Alex     | Grey     | 0000
James    | Garnder  | 2489
```

I want to search Column C for duplicates. So, the query would find that rows 1 and 2 contain duplicated values in Column C, as well as rows 3 and 5. So, where found, I need it to return all fields for all three columns where column C contains duplicates. So the result I want is this:

```
Peter    | Smith    | 1234
Claire   | Walter   | 1234
Sandra   | Kay      | 0000
Alex     | Grey     | 0000
```

I read several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields) and [this last one](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select-distinct) which was the most helpful in that by using SELECT DISTINCT it did return only the UNIQUE values (and therefore excluded duplicate ones), but that is visa versa to what I want, and it did not also return the Columns A and B with the results.  The suggestions in the earlier two posts just keep returning empty results when I know there are duplicate values in the database.

Hoping someone could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have query which first gets all duplicate values based on that particular column and retrieve records which is in that duplicate values.

Your query should be like this :

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C
FROM your_table 
WHERE Column_C IN (
    SELECT Column_C
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Column_C
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect and worked exactly as I needed first time. I spent hours trying to find the answer, you did so within minutes. Very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `GROUP BY` statement like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM T 
WHERE C IN (SELECT C
            FROM T
            GROUP BY C
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: This does not return all rows.

Comment: @CL. Can you explain further?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your GROUP BY clause. But this query does not search for duplicates only in column `C`.

Comment: @CL. You are right. I just fixed my answer to fit in this.